# Mysql server crash on start

Tags: mysql

Mysql server crash on start on my Ubuntu 12.04.2 server. Mysql just not starting. Not after reboot, not after `service mysql start`(it return `start: Job failed to start`).

Previously it worked fine, but at some point the server crashed and I was not able to run it.

/var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
151109 10:02:14 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151109 10:02:14 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151109 10:02:14 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151109 10:02:14 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
151109 10:02:14 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
151109 10:02:14 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 5.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
151109 10:02:15  InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex 76607...(I removed the part)...3c3f438045ca5727; asc v`                  E W1                   9                           -       .       /       0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       :       ;       <       =       >       ?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       !       "       #       $       %       &       '       (       )       *       +       ,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             _   @       _   @    jPs                                                                                                                                                           <?C E W';
InnoDB: End of page dump
151109 10:02:15  InnoDB: Page checksum 1986035693, prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum 3548252131
InnoDB: stored checksum 1986035693, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 1010779008
InnoDB: Page lsn 0 1170888497, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 1170888487
InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 5,
InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be a transaction system page
InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed
InnoDB: file read of page 5.
InnoDB: You may have to recover from a backup.
InnoDB: It is also possible that your operating
InnoDB: system has corrupted its own file cache
InnoDB: and rebooting your computer removes the
InnoDB: error.
InnoDB: If the corrupt page is an index page
InnoDB: you can also try to fix the corruption
InnoDB: by dumping, dropping, and reimporting
InnoDB: the corrupt table. You can use CHECK
InnoDB: TABLE to scan your table for corruption.
InnoDB: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
151109 10:02:15  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3065161472 in file buf0buf.c line 3629
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
10:02:15 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346064 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb733d003]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484)[0xb71e9f24]
[0xb6ea0400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x590e78)[0xb7453e78]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x591852)[0xb7454852]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x58109a)[0xb744409a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x54f75d)[0xb741275d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551d09)[0xb7414d09]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x53d5e0)[0xb74005e0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x501a22)[0xb73c4a22]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x4e)[0xb71ec74e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1fbd82)[0xb70bed82]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xbc3)[0xb70c2723]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x16691a)[0xb702991a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x66a)[0xb702d61a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(main+0x27)[0xb7022d27]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb6b5f4d3]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Comment: see thishttps://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-know-the-reason-mysql-keep-crashing

Comment: I've already set up swap. Adding memory also did not help.

Comment: Swap and available memory are not the issue.  Note the error: `Database page corruption on disk... you may have to recover from a backup.`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.